# About (boolean-algebra) tag

Tags: discussion, tagging

Boolean algebra has two common meanings - an order-theoretic [structure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_algebra_%28structure%29) or "algebra of logic", i.e. basic calculus with truth values.

Currently the wiki excerpt looks like this:

> Boolean algebras are structures which behave similar to a power set with complement, intersection and union. Questions regarding Boolean algebras as structures, or regarding functions defined from/to Boolean algebras fit into this tag very nicely.

To me this description looks like it should be about Boolean algebras as structures, but perhaps the last sentence might be understood in a such way that it includes the second meaning too.

There are both types of questions tagged with this tag.
E.g. these questions [[boolean-algebra]+truth+table](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=[boolean-algebra]+truth+table) seem to be about truth values and these questions [[boolean-algebra]+lattice](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=[boolean-algebra]+lattice) are mostly about BAs as structures, to list a few examples.

The possible things as I see them are:

- We can keep both types of questions under the same tag, they're related closely enough to be in the same category. No changes are necessary.
- We can retag some of the questions to [boolean-algebra-structure](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/boolean-algebra-structure) (or some similar tag) and rewrite tag wikis accordingly.
- We don't need a special tag for questions about truth-values and truth-tables, they can be tagged under [logic](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/logic). Tag-excerpt and tag-wiki for [boolean-algebra](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/boolean-algebra) should include the information that such questions are not supposed to be there.

I will post these options as answers, so that they can be down/upvoted and we can reach some consensus about it. If I did not include some other reasonable possibility, please, add it as an answer.

NOTE: I did not post this to the long thread we have about tags. The reason is that there are several options to choose between and in that thread there is only possibility to upvote downvote.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We can keep both types of questions under the same tag, they're related closely enough to be in the same category. No changes are necessary.

Comment: I guess 6 upvotes for this answer can be considered a consensus, so I accepted this answer.

Answer (score 2):

We don't need a special tag for questions about truth-values and truth-tables, they can be tagged under [logic](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/logic) or (perhaps better) [propositional-calculus](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/propositional-calculus).

Tag-excerpt and tag-wiki for [boolean-algebra](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/boolean-algebra) should include the information that such questions are not supposed to be there.

Answer (score -1):

I would suggest starting a tag for [boolean-logic](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/boolean-logic) as synonym for [propositional-logic](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/propositional-logic) (or maybe even as a tag on its own) Boolean logic normally uses a little bit different notation, they are comparable but not everybody knows how to change between them

PS I wanted to do this in a new question, but then saw this (old question)

It is just that in some sectors propositional logic is unknown, they just speak about Boolean logic, and the only tag starting with Boolean.....

Answer (score -2):

We should retag some of the questions to [boolean-algebra-structure](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/boolean-algebra-structure) (or some similar name) and rewrite tag wikis accordingly.

(Please, if you have better suggestion for the name of the tag, write it in the comments or edit this answer.)